# Replicator/ReplicatorBuilder ignores URI credentials

Tags: java, android, couchdb, cloudant

I'm using Cloudant-sync android latest release so far: 2.0.2 and targeting Android api 21+.
My server database is CouchDB 2.1.0

I'm trying to trigger a replication pull from my android app, to update the local db.
I'm giving the source URI to the ReplicatorBuilder like: 
"https: //user:password@databaseurl/db_name"
(as specificated here https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/replication.md)
but in the generated replicator object, if I inspect "replicator.strategy.sourceDb" the db uri is just 
"https: //databaseurl/db_name" and so, i get unhautorized (it works fine if I deactivate the security check on the database server)

This is my running code:

```
public ReplicationListener pullAllAsync(Databases db_name) {
    try {
        URI uri = db_name.getServerURI();
        DocumentStore ds = DocumentStore.getInstance(new File(db_name.getMobilePath(), db_name.toString()));
        Replicator replicator = ReplicatorBuilder.pull().from(uri).to(ds).build();
        ReplicationListener listener = new ReplicationListener(replicator);
        replicator.getEventBus().register(listener);
        replicator.start();
        return listener;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LogRepository.getInstance().escribirLog(LogRepository.TipoLog.ERROR, null, e, true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste your code here. Not images of it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited already. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem seems to be with the CookieAuthentication (which is the default authentication method of the Replicator when creds are passed with in the URI)
I don't really know why is it failing, because the CouchDB server instance is configured to accept CookieAuthentication.

Anyway, this may not be the best possible solution, but is a good enough workaround. I have made this work by forcing the BasicAuthentication method as follows:

```
public ReplicationListener pullAllAsync(Databases db_name) {
    try {
        URI uri = db_name.getServerURI();

        DocumentStore ds = DocumentStore.getInstance(new File(db_name.getMobilePath(), db_name.toString()));
        Replicator replicator = ReplicatorBuilder
                .pull()
                .from(uri)
                .to(ds)

                //WORKAROUND: forces BasicAuthentication method instead of CookieAuthentication
                .addRequestInterceptors(new BasicAuthInterceptor(uri.getRawUserInfo()))
                .build();

        ReplicationListener listener = new ReplicationListener(replicator);
        replicator.getEventBus().register(listener);
        replicator.start();
        return listener;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LogRepository.getInstance().escribirLog(LogRepository.TipoLog.ERROR, null, e, true);
        return null;
    }
}
```